# Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpExceptionsgr

Tags: php

When I click on post button I get next error:

Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException No message
Here is my code, situated in blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> PHP Basics </title>
</head>
</body>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
        Guest name:<input type="text" name="guest_name" value="Arsen" required>
        <input type="submit">
</form>

<?php

    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        $guest_name = $_POST['guest_name'];
        echo "Hello, $guest_name!<br>";
    }

    echo "</div>";

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How it is connected with laravel? This can be done without any framework.

Comment: maybe you are right, but i did with laravel , so decided specify  this tag

Comment: you should check methods of form action url in route file. probably you have defined just `GET` method. so either add post to allowed methods or change form method to GET.

Answer (score 0):

Your getting that error because you didn't able to declare the route from laravel.

Instead of using the

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
        Guest name:<input type="text" name="guest_name" value="Arsen" required>
        <input type="submit">
</form>
```

You must do something like this

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('myroutename')}}"> 
    <!-- csrf_field()  This is the validation of valid post request -->    
     {{ csrf_field() }}      
     Guest name:<input type="text" name="guest_name" value="Arsen" required>
     <input type="submit">
</form>
```

and  in your `route.php or web.php`

```
Route::get('/my-route-name', 'MyModelController@store')->name('myroutename');
```

Hope that this will give you an idea how to fix this kind of problem.